# To select a row in a table that has javascript behind the code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using `selenium webdriver` in `java` and got stuck at a place. Actually there is a table on page in which on selecting each row the page posts back and take user to next page. In `HTML` `javascript` is being used. The `HTML` of page looks like this:-

```
    <td>onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$DefaultContent$WorklistCtrl$WorklistView',
'Select$4')"
onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none';" 
onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';"
style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none;" kalis, jack </td>
```

This is a row data in a table on which I want to click.It shows kalis,jack in the table cell and behind it this code is placed. When I place mouse over this it acts like a link but not able to click it using `webdriver` in `selenium`.

Please help.Thanks in advance

Comment: The <td> tag is closed before the onclick, onmouseout and onmouseover attributes

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[cotains(text(),'kalis, jack')"));
    ele.click();
```

or

```
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[cotains(text(),'kalis, jack')"));
    new Actions(driver).moveToElement(ele).perform();
    ele.click();
```

Comment: How is the "driver" variable defined?

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement cell = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='']/tr[x]/td[y]"));
dell.click();
```

**Exemple : let's catch the cell 4**

```
<table id="tb123"> //table
  <tr> //table/tr[0]
    <td>Cell 1</td> //table/tr[0]/td[0] 
    <td>Cell 2</td> //table/tr[0]/td[1] 
  </tr>
  <tr> //table/tr[1]
    <td>Cell 3</td> //table/tr[1]/td[0]
    <td>Cell 4</td> //table/tr[1]/td[1]
  </tr>
</table>
```

Your xpath is going to be like that : //table[@id='tb123']/tr[1]/td[1]

Answer (score 0):

When clicking on link, does it opens a new pop-up window or just navigate to other page?

Below are related your problem. Have a look,

[Problem using Selenium to automate a postback link that is inside an ASP.NET UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419532/problem-using-selenium-to-automate-a-postback-link-that-is-inside-an-asp-net-upd)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/selenium-users/pYEZR7OAfpA